# Creating menu from JSON data in laravel blade views

Tags: php, json, laravel, menuitem, submenu

I'm trying to have `multi level menu` through `JSON data`, following is my `JSON` format data:

```
{"pages": [
        {"pagelink": "index.html", "pagename": "Mysite", "submenu": [
                    {"pagelink": "#", "pagename": "sublevel1", "submenu": "NULL"},
                    {"pagelink": "#", "pagename": "submenu2", "submenu": [

                        {"pagelink": "#", "pagename": "sublevel2", "submenu": "NULL"}

                        ]
                    }
                ]
        }, 
        {"pagelink": "templates.html", "pagename": "Templates", "submenu": "NULL"}, 
        {"pagelink": "aboutus.html", "pagename": "About Us", "submenu": "NULL"}, 
        {"pagelink": "contactus.html", "pagename": "Contact Us", "submenu": "NULL"}
    ]
}
```

When I was not having `sub menu` field I used to call the menu by following:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="main-nav" class="hidden-mobile">
        @foreach($contents->pages as $pages)
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="{{ $pages->pagelink }}">{{ $pages->pagename }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I added submenu I tried using following code:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="main-nav" class="hidden-mobile">
        @foreach($contents->pages as $pages)
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="{{ $pages->pagelink }}">{{ $pages->pagename }}</a>
                @if(isset($contents->pages->submenu))
                     <ul class="sub-nav">
                        @foreach($contents->pages->submenu as $submenu)
                            <li><a href="{{ $submenu->pagelink }}">{{ $submenu->pagename }}</a> </li>
                        @endforeach
                     </ul>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But it is not working out.

Please guide me, shall I need to change `JSON data` format or the is there any way out in `blade` file itself.

Comment: What is the output of above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `$pages`, not `$contents->pages`

```
@if(isset($pages->submenu))
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        @foreach($pages->submenu as $submenu)
            <li><a href="{{ $submenu->pagelink }}">{{ $submenu->pagename }}</a> </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

---

If you would like to create multidimensional JSON, and you don't know, how many nested arrays you will have, you have to create additional blade for submenu

```
<ul class="sub-nav">
    @foreach($pages as $submenu)
        <li>
            <a href="{{ $submenu->pagelink }}">{{ $submenu->pagename }}</a>
            @if (isset($submenu->submenu))
                @include('submenu', ['pages' => $submenu->submenu])
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

And then your menu blade will looks like:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="main-nav" class="hidden-mobile">
        @foreach($contents->pages as $pages)
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="{{ $pages->pagelink }}">{{ $pages->pagename }}</a>
                @if(isset($pages->submenu))
                    @include('submenu', ['pages' => $pages->submenu])
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This solution should work, if you will remove `"submenu": "NULL"`. If not, you have to additionally check, if element `submenu` is an array in all conditionals.

Comment: That was silly, I understood, but still I'm getting `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` that's because of the NULL which I'm trying to push.

Comment: True, because you are putting string "NULL", what is not equal to `null`. You have to remove `"submenu": "NULL"` from JSON or you have to check in blade if `$pages->submenu` is also an array `@if(isset($pages->submenu) && is_array($pages->submenu))`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not able to get the third level i.e. `"pagename": "sublevel2" `

Comment: I was exactly looking for the same, thanks for your help..:)